# How is another root -i?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this equation
$$ix^{2}-2(i+1)x+(i-1)=0$$
one root is  $i-1$ and another root is $-i$. How is it possible?

Solution I have tried :

Assume two roots are $A_1,A_2$ then $A_1+A_2=-b/a$ and $A_1A_2=c/a$. By using this formula I'm getting another root as $1/i$ not $-i$ but the correct answer is $-i$.

Comment: @SophieClad that's what how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple, you got $1/i$. See, $i^{-1}=-i$ because $i\cdot(-i)=1$, and if $xy=1$ then $x^{-1}=y$, here assume $y$ as $-i$

Answer (score 11):

$\frac {1}{i}$ = $-i$ .

To see this Multiply numerator and denominator of $\frac {1}{i}$ by   $ i $

Comment: i know $i^2=-1$ but how it's possible that square of any number is equals to $-1$

Comment: Since $i\cdot(-i)$ equals $1$ that tells us $i^{-1}$ is $-i$.

Comment: @anon How $i.(-i)=1$ tells $i^(-1) is -i$

Comment: $ab=1$ means $a^{-1}=b$.

Comment: @SophieClad that is only true of quadratic equations with coefficients in R

Comment: In the question, $i$ is not a constant, it equals an imaginary number, $\sqrt{-1}$. @MahenderReddyYasa